# How to pass the variables in model#create to model#show after redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a photo_link variable which I want to display in the show.html

so I click create in the view, and it brings me to effects#create

```
  def create
    @effect = Effect.new(effect_params)
    @effect.save
    @pid = params[:effect][:pid]
    @photo_link = apply_effect1(@pid)
    respond_with(@effect)
  end
```

When I check the log, I think it is redirect to effects#show before display to show.html

```
Started POST "/effects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-19 13:56:21 +1100
Processing by EffectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zFqMGJkUQeSs+KqUI1ewWl1t6beEc9LZaRRlI8TKrCY=", "effect"=>{"effect1"=>"0", "effect2"=>"0", "effect3"=>"0", "pid"=>"37"}, "commit"=>"Create Effect"}
Unpermitted parameters: pid
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "effects" ("created_at", "effect1", "effect2", "effect3", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-10-19 02:56:21.056844"], ["effect1", "f"], ["effect2", "f"], ["effect3", "f"], ["updated_at", "2014-10-19 02:56:21.056844"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
"37"
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 37]]

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/effects/60
Completed 302 Found in 704ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started GET "/effects/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-19 13:56:21 +1100
Processing by EffectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"60"}
  Effect Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "effects".* FROM "effects"  WHERE "effects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 60]]
  Rendered effects/show.html.erb within layouts/loginpage (0.6ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 391ms (Views: 388.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

and here is my effect#show

```
  def show
    p "HIHI IM HERE"
    p params
    respond_with(@effect)
  end
```

Is there anyway I can pass `@photo_link` to show.html ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`respond_with` will, by default, redirect you to the show action. What you want to do is customise the `location` param of `respond_with`, so you get redirected to the correct place (in this case, still the show action, but with extra parameters). See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

I think it's something like:

```
respond_with(@effect, location: effect_show_path(@effect, @photo_link))
```